# execution time limit for script

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp

Sorry for my english I will try to translate as best as possible. This is my first time in this forum, sorry if the topic was already writen.

I am trying to import a MySQL DB in my phpmyadmin using MAMP. The DB is big (almost 600MB and 350 tables...!)

I have an error message saying the time limit for the script is reached. After is an uncomprenhensible code that a will paste further.

The first 75 tables are imported (in alphabetical order) but not the rest... (stops at c letter)

I have searched on the web for a solution and I found a lot of interesting parameters but nothing works for me.

I have modified file php.ini in mamp > bin > php > php7.4.33 > php.ini

- post_max_size = 2000M
- upload_max_filesize = 1000M
- memory_limit = 2000M
- max_execution_time = 3000
- max_input_time = 2000
- max_file_uploads = 2000

I have modified file config.default.php in mamp > bin > phpmyadmin (and also
phpmyadmin5) > libraries > config.default.php

- $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;

Have tried in zipping the DB and re-import...
Have export again from the web hosting and re-import...
Nothing works...

The error message was followed by this uncomprehensible code :
`-- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Table structure for table` pss_avalara_product_cache`-- CREATE TABLE`pss_avalara_product_cache`(`id_cache`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`id_product`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`tax_rate`float(8,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`region`varchar(2) NOT NULL,`id_address`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`update_date`datetime DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;-- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Table structure for table`pss_avalara_returned_products`-- CREATE TABLE`pss_avalara_returned_products`(`id_returned_product`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`id_order`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`id_product`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`total`float(8,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`quantity`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`name`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`description_short`varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`tax_code`varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

I tried to export the DB from web hosting without those two tables... but a get a new table with the same problem... I think this is not a good solution.

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have command line access to mysql? It might be better to import that way

Comment: There is a terminal in phpmyadmin. I tried "mysql -u username -p database_name < my_unzipped_import_file.sql" (putting the right user, db-name and file), but it didn't work. Obviously I don't know how to use the command line...

Comment: You log onto the mysql server, open a terminal window, and run the mysql command from there. First though you must of course upload the script file onto the server

Comment: What do you mean by "mysql server" ? I use phpmyadmin. Is that it ? And what is the "script file"? It's the .sql file ? That's what I'm trying to upload but the command doesn't work...

Comment: ??? phpmyadmin is just an administration tool which lets you manage databases in a mysql (or mariaDB) server. It doesn't contain any data itself. It's only one of many such administration tools you can use for this purpose (one of which is the mysql command-line interface). It's a bit worrying that you have such little understanding of the tools you are using, or your operating environment. It's hard to be successful if you don't even know the basics of the architecture.

Comment: And by "script file"  I mean the SQL file you are trying to upload and execute via phpyadmin. You could try to execute it using a different tool instead, so that you don't get (what appears to be) a timeout due to having to upload a very large file over HTTP - although to be fair you've posted no proper error information or anything else so it's difficult to be certain if it's that, or if the SQL script contains an error and crashed.

Comment: More background info (which you really should have looked at before now): https://www.phpmyadmin.net/, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/what-is-mysql.html, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html, https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/, https://www.google.com/search?q=MySQL+admin+tools

Comment: Well... yes I am learning ! Thank you for the infos and sorry to bother you.